# which type of indicator is on this dialog box?

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-custom-view, indicator

i just wanted to know whether someone could tell me which type of indicator is on this dialog box to the left:

[image]
How is that indicator called and how can I achieve this green border?

EDIT:

Okay probably these are checkboxes... But how do I get some similar design to these green borders?

Answer (score 2):

It is a custom drawable, there's no predefined indicator to do this.